# Proving $|A\cup B|\le_c |A|+|B|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I'm using the notation from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3152232/problem-of-cardinal-assignment) question.

> For all sets $A,B$, $|A\cup B|\le_c |A|+|B|$, and if $A\cap B=\emptyset$ then $|A\cup B|=_c |A|+|B|$.

My attempt to prove it:

By definition, $$|A|+|B|=||A|\coprod|B||.$$ $|A\cup B|\le_c |A|+|B|$ means that there is an injection from $|A\cup B|$ to $|A|+|B|=||A|\coprod|B||$. Since for any set $S$, $S=_c |S|$, it suffices to show that there is an injection from $A\cup B$ to $|A|\coprod |B|=(\text{blue}\times|A|)\cup (\text{red}\times|B|)$. (Here $\text{blue}=\{blue\}$ and similarly for $\text{red}$.)

For a set $S$, let $f_S: S\to |S|$ be a bijection. Define a function $$f:A\cup B\to |A|\coprod |B|$$ as follows. If $x\in A$, then $f(x)=(blue,f_A(x))$. If $x\in B$, then $f(x)=(red,f_B(x))$. It is obviously injective as long as it is well defined. But why is it well-defined? If $x\in A\cap B$, then $f(x)=(blue,f_A(x))$ and $f(x)=(red,f_B(x))$...

If $A\cap B=\emptyset$, then $f$ is well-defined and injective. How to show it is surjective (if it is)?

Comment: It is not well-defined. You are sending the elements of $A\cap B$ to both $(\text{blue},A)$ and to $(\text{red},B)$. Send them only to one of the two. For example, $f(x)=(\text{blue},x)$ for $x\in A$ and $f(x)=(\text{red},B)$ for $x\in B\setminus A$. For the second part, note that if $A\cap B=\emptyset$, then $B\setminus A=B$.

Comment: Your function won't be well-defined in general, but if you change "If $x\in B$..." to something else, then you can make it well defined.

Comment: About the surjectivity of the redefined function: suppose $(blue,z)\in |A|\coprod |B|$, then $(blue,z)=(blue,f_A(z'))$ for some $z'\in A$, so $z'$ maps to $(blue,z)$. Similarly an element of the form $(red,z)$ has a preimage. But I don't see how this uses the fact that $A\cap B=\emptyset$.

Comment: It is much more useful to prove |A $\cup$ B| + |A $\cap$  B| = |A| + |B|.

Comment: What do $\le_c$ and $=_c$ mean? Do they just mean $\le$ and $=$ or do they mean something else?

Comment: @bof $A=_c B$ means that there is a bijection from $A$ to $B$. $A\le_c B$ means that there is an injection from $A$ to $B$.

Comment: So $A=_c B$ means that $A$ and $B$ have the same cardinality, i.e., that $|A|=|B|$, where $|A|$ is the cardinality of the set $A$; and $A\le_c B$ means that the cardinality of $A$ is less that or equal to the cardinality of $B$, that is, $|A|\le|B|$. Got it.

Comment: @user647486 Is the condition $B-A=B$ supposed to imply surjectivity? If so, I don't see how; my comment above seems to prove surjectivity without that assumption...

Comment: @logic If $A\cap B=\setminus$, then $B\setminus A= B$. This means that if $(\text{red},x)\in\{\text{red}\}\times B$, then $x\in B=B\setminus A\subset A\cup B$ satisfies that $f(x)=(\text{blue},x)$. Therefore, $f$ is onto on the $\{\text{red}\}\times B$. It is always onto (the $f$ that I defined in my first comment) on the $\{\text{blue}\}\times A$ part.